# Tickerid function to identify the ticker

Tags: if-statement, pine-script, ticker

I cannot find a way in which the command tickerid works for me..
I want to make an IF statment where

If (the current ticker i'm on = a specific ticker i've put)
then (execute a formula)
else
(do nothing)

So i want my indicator to work in different parameters depending on the assets.

Can someone help me what command i should use ?

Answer (score 4):

An example.
This will change the background color, depending on the ticker you select.

```
//@version=4
study(title="TickerId", shorttitle="TCK", overlay=true)

var color   myColor = na

if barstate.isfirst
    if syminfo.ticker == "AAPL"
        myColor := color.red
    else if syminfo.ticker == "MSFT"
        myColor := color.green
    else if syminfo.ticker == "TSLA"
        myColor := color.blue
    else
        myColor := na

bgcolor(myColor)
```

**Edit 1** in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66674121/tickerid-function-to-identify-the-ticker/66674302?noredirect=1#comment117863769_66674302).
When you declare a variable, and initialize it with `na`, you need to specify the type of the variable.
Also, in your case, `syminfo.tickerid` must be used instead of `syminfo.ticker`, because I see that you use the format `EXCHANGE:SYMBOL`.
The code below will work.
Please remember to add the `//@version=4` tag in the beginning of your script.

```
//@version=4
study(title="TickerId", shorttitle="TCK", overlay=true, scale=scale.left)

var int Periods = input(20, "Periods")

var color   myColor = na
var float   ATR     = na 

if syminfo.tickerid == "CAPITALCOM:US100"
    ATR := atr(Periods) * 1.9
    myColor := color.green
else 
    ATR := atr(Periods) 
    myColor := color.red

plot(ATR)
bgcolor(myColor)
```

Comment: Added Edit 1 to my answer.